# Why im getting this 'bezier' error on my react native project

Tags: react-native

I'm not an expert on react native and this issue is for cli project not expo. I get an error when I try to use this dependency https://github.com/alexZajac/react-native-skeleton-content-nonexpo#examples.

I did some research I found it's a reactanimed version problem I changed it but still the same problem.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "munchyapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.1",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^4.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "is_js": "^0.9.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.4",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.4.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-skeleton-content-nonexpo": "^1.0.13",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.2.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.13",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

My App.tsx

```
import {SafeAreaView, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import SkeletonContent from 'react-native-skeleton-content-nonexpo';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <SkeletonContent
        containerStyle={{flex: 1, width: 300}}
        isLoading={true}
        layout={[
          {key: 'someId', width: 220, height: 20, marginBottom: 6},
          {key: 'someOtherId', width: 180, height: 20, marginBottom: 6},
        ]}>
        <Text>Your content</Text>
        <Text>Other content</Text>
      </SkeletonContent>
      <Text>Test</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

issue image
[image]

Constants.js content

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const react_native_reanimated_1 = require("react-native-reanimated");
exports.DEFAULT_BORDER_RADIUS = 4;
exports.DEFAULT_DURATION = 1200;
exports.DEFAULT_ANIMATION_TYPE = 'shiver';
exports.DEFAULT_ANIMATION_DIRECTION = 'horizontalRight';
exports.DEFAULT_BONE_COLOR = '#E1E9EE';
exports.DEFAULT_HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = '#F2F8FC';
exports.DEFAULT_EASING = react_native_reanimated_1.EasingNode.bezier(0.5, 0, 0.25, 1);
exports.DEFAULT_LOADING = true;
```

Comment: can you check this link ? https://github.com/alexZajac/react-native-skeleton-content-nonexpo/issues/38

Comment: The last answer ???

Comment: yes please see if the link helps resolves your issue

Comment: The link is not found https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/migration

Comment: Im also using the version 3.0.2:  `"react-native-reanimated": "^3.0.2"`